# JavaFX & Laravel | XAMPP or MySQL Workbench or both?

Tags: java, mysql, laravel, xampp

I have dilemma with Java & Laravel *MySQL* setup.

> **TLDR;** How do I setup **Java** & **Laravel** Development Environment?

Can **Laravel** be done using **XAMPP**?

Can **Java** be done using **XAMPP**?

If you already had **XAMPP** (*phpMyAdmin*), does **MySQL Workbench** became useless?

Comment: Yes `Laravel` can be done with `XAMPP`, `Java` can't be done. If you have `phpmyadmin` you will not need My sql Workbench

Comment: Um, so what I'm gonna need for my Java Development?

Comment: No, idea abbout java

Comment: No, I mean can I use MySQL from XAMPP with Java?

Comment: I just want to connect Java to MySql (XAMPP) So I can store data to its Database/schema.